# Remote process creates an user profile entry (on remote box)?

Tags: c#, psexec

I believe it is not an issue, but curious to find out more on how to avoid it

When a .Net application (written in C#), which starts a remote process on another machine on same network that make a psexec or ManagementScope call, it creates user profile folder on remote machine.

for ex. let us say, your ID is -tom.cat, once remote process is completed, you navigate to C:\Users (folder in Win7) there is new folder created as "tom.cat" along with local user and other users who have logged on to that box.

Is there anyway to avoid this folder creation?

Comment: Does the box have a domain controller for login authentication

Answer (score 0):

Individually, each tool has it's own method for Logging a User onto the workstation so that it can create a process running as that user.

Under the hood, this probably looks very much like:

```
LogonUser();
LoadUserProfile();
```

Which, of course, causes the profile to be created. And there's probably a very good reason why they need the profile to exist. Perhaps they need to target part of the user's environment, like the user's TEMP directory. Or they need to persist information in the registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

The only hope you may have would be on a tool-specific basis, where a particular utility has a command-line arg to cause it to NOT attempt to load the profile when run. Of course, this may reduce functionality. For example `psexec` [has the '-e' command line argument](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to not load the specified user's profile. But beware what that could mean to the command that psexec is launching.

ManagementScope's [ConnectionOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not appear to have a member that allows you to direct the call to not load a profile.

Comment: Thanks **Lynn Crumbling** for your detailed answer.

Comment: @EditOR Glad to help.